# Angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm using Mapkitjs to create a map, and it initialized via window object, on the server i see error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

How i can add script into the server for fix that error?
I tried

```
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
const script = win.document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js';
win.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bypass the server side as it does not support DOM-associated stuffs.

Example:

```js
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

...
isBrowser: boolean;

constructor(
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId
) {
  this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
}

...

if (this.isBrowser) {
  // Put your code here
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that code will work only in the browser, and server doesn't init and render the map, right?

Comment: @IgorZinchenko user can see the browser only. the server code is mostly used for SEO-like special purposes only, so not rendering the map DOM on the server side doesnt actually matter

Comment: so, for SEO map is not required?

Comment: not required. Instead, you can leave some minimal info about the lat and lng on server side.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! ) please post your feedback in the answer)